# Restore deleted .git folder from GitHub

Tags: git, github

I have continued working with GitHub Visual Studio extension and accidentally deleted `.git` folder from my local repository.
Is there a way to download `.git` folder from GitHub to my repository?

Comment: Your .git repository shouldn't exist on GitHub -- it only exists locally on your machine. It's what the git program on your computer uses to keep track of what repository you're in and what changes you've made locally and so forth.

Comment: I think you can publish

Comment: Move the folder to save your working changes, `git clone` again, and copy the folder contents back.

Comment: Ok clear but how do for upload all commit that i have launched with visual studio extension?

Comment: @Dan Hi Dan! Sorry but i don't understand :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you accidentally deleted a `.git` folder in your local working copy, and want to restore it from remote repository (e.g. on GitHub), then the following should work (assuming that you are in the root directory where you want to put `.git` folder):

```
git init
git remote add origin <url>
git fetch
git reset origin/master
```

Here `<url>` is the URL of the remote repository (for instance, `git@github.com:git/git.git` or `https://github.com/git/git.git`).

Answer (score 1):

Yes is correct!! Download the entire remote repository or clone it. Now i try to clone and automatically appear .git repository with all commit from github

Comment: You'd better update your question rather then creating this answer.